# How to find a polynomial of two variables with 2 local extrema

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How could I find the simplest polynomial $P[x,y]=\sum_{0\leq i,0\leq j} \alpha_{ij} x^i y^j$ with only $N$ local extrema ? I'm mostly interested in the cases $N=2$ and $N=3$.

Meaning there are only $N$ solutions for the system {$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=0,\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=0\}$

Comment: The title does not reflect the question. Do you want two local extrema or two critical points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $N=2$ local *extrema*, a suitable [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval) works. For instance,
$$
((x-a)^{2}+y^{2})((x+a)^{2}+y^{2})=b^{4}
$$
with $a=1$ and $b^4=0.9$, which gives

[image]

For $N=3$, this sextic works:
$$
(x^2 +y^2 −1)(x^2 +y^2 −2)(x^2 +y^2 −3)+x^6=0
$$

[image]

I don't know whether these are the simplest you can get, but I expect you'll need degree at least $2N$.

I learned about the sextic in the paper [Sixty-Four Curves of Degree Six](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01660).